# How to use ACF Pro Flexible Content with Single Page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m developing a website with flexible content. I’m using it as a builder basically.

I’m in the page section, e.g. Portfolio, and I can “Add row”. Awesome! All of these pages are using `page.php` where this code is displayed:

```
<?php 

if( have_rows('template_blocks') ):

while ( have_rows('template_blocks') ) : the_row();

    if( get_row_layout() == 'header_page' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'header-page' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'header_main' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'header-main' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'services_excerpt' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'services-excerpt' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'contact' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'contact' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'services_tabs' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'services-tabs' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'standards' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'standards' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'contact' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'contact' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'footer' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'footer' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'bar_secondary' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'bar-secondary' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'process' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'process' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'empty_bar' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'empty-bar' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'form_section' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'form-section' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'callout' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'callout' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'ready_bar' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'ready-bar' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'portfolio_excerpt' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'portfolio-excerpt' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'services_card' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'services-card' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'about_author' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'about-author' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'work_featured' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'work-featured' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'work_all' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'work-all' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'work_tab' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'work-tab' );

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'action_block' ):
       get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'action-block' );
    endif;

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

However, now I created a custom post type

Custom Fields ->
Show this field group in:
Post Type [is equal to] [Projects]

So I go ahead and create few projects. Now, in the code, I get the WP Query, so I can take these projects.

However, now I click a project, and where it goes? It goes to `single.php` page! How do I edit `single.php` page? There is no option like for a normal page.

How do I say, add a single page for portfolio, and add the flexible content?

Sure, I can add in the same code that that is in `page.php`, but so what? Where do I go to view the single page in the WP admin dashboard?

I know it’s possible.

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, and I can’t figure it out.

Here is the github repo if that helps: https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/aurelianMegaPortfolio2018

Currently, I have: Home, Services, Process, About, Contact, Portfolio.

All of them are using `page.php`, and when I go to Admin Dashboard page, I just ‘Add row’, and that way I can achieve a unique look for every single page that I mentioned, apart from `single.php`, because how do I make `single.php` for projects? or services?

Comment: You should show how you created that custom post type. When you create a custom post type, you have to define some parameters - and that may modify whether your custom post type is "post-like" or "page-like". They have different attributes, and they are handled differently.

Comment: And also you'd be better off with a PHP **switch** than a ton of if-elseif-elseif... and that last **endif;** at the end of the code block - does it have an opening **if**?

Comment: Switch won't work in this case, if I'm correct, but either way I might to di another way, a cleaer way, so far I'm just trying to get this working. 

Here is the repo - https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/aurelianMegaPortfolio2018

Here are some screensots - https://imgur.com/a/b8Ajm

Problem is, if I set it to be e..g portfolio

This is custom post type

But the structure
Template Blocks, need to be shown on every single-[projects].php
so far, this will show only on the single project

Comment: I'm coding every single piece my self, but problem is, single-[custom-post-type.php

As there is no option to change that
I mean.. you can do it, but it will reflect on one page. So if I assing it to be Project page, the Template Blocks, I will need to go to every single project page... which that's a horrible way to go on about it.

Answer (score 0):

Custom post types do not use the `page.php` file and will default to use `single.php`. You can specify a unique file template by creating a version of the file that has the name of the custom post type appended to it, like this: `single-{post-type-name}.php`.

In your case, it sounds like that will be `single-projects.php`.

You can likely just create this page using a duplicate of your `page.php`.

Here is a link to reference the WordPress template structure. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Not sure what I supposed to do. I set custom post type to be displayed on a page.php, which means I can select or do anything I want, e.g. add a new field. Yes, I know how to do all of that. I know the template hierarchy, but my point is, how can I use 'flexible content' on a single-[custom-post-type].php? You know page.php, I can use flexible content, 'Add Row' and the page will be style. Each page will be different, depending what I 'Add' to it. They all will use page.php. Now, there is no way for me to control single-cusomt-post-type.php page in the UI, same way like a page.php.